# Using SSL for multiple CNames

Tags: 2010, ssl

I have a SharePoint 2010 install with a single web site on port 80.  I recently added a wildcard SSL Cert to IIS7 on the server and added a binding for my SharePoint site.

So far, so good.  The SharePoint site now supports `https://servername/sites/whatever` just fine.

But I have users that want friendlier server names such as "engineering" and "hr", but here's the key, they want them on the same web site.  This means `http://servername/sites/whatever` would be the same as `http://engineering/sites/whatever`.

Not a problem, I just had our server team create a couple of CNAME records and point them at the server, then used Alternate Access Mappings to get SharePoint to recognize them.

**Now my problem**

I can't get SSL working for the other names.  I tried adding them through IIS, but keep getting this message:

> "This binding is already being used by a product other than iis..."

[image]

Is this something i should even use IIS to configure?  Can I do this through SharePoint Central Administration?

Comment: How did you add the Alternate Access Mappings? Did you do it the right way by extending the web app into each extra zone?

Comment: Ahh, no I did not.  So that means I would have to create extra web sites for each name via extending?